# JS - Array de objetos para array de arrays

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Como faço para converter um array de objetos para um array de arrays no javascript? Fiz dessa forma, porém retorna um array de objetos

```
var items1 = new Array();


 $.map(objResposta, function(value,index) {
       teste = new Array();
       items1.push(value);
       teste.push(items1);

 });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que os valores que estão em vermelho fiquem no array desta forma:

```
Array [ ['resposta atualizada', 5], ['esse foi', 4] ]
```

Existe alguma maneira de popular assim?

Comment: Você quer para um caso genérico ou apenas para esse array específico?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Já tens uma array... uma array com objetos, tens de converter numa array de arrays.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const array = [{
    nomePergunta: 'resposta atualizada',
    quantidadeResposta: 5
}, {
    nomePergunta: 'esse foi',
    quantidadeResposta: 4
}];

const novaArray = array.map(el => Object.keys(el).map(key => el[key]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(novaArray));
```

A ideia é:

- pega a array inicial
- converte cada objeto numa array das suas chaves/propriedades
- mapeia esse array de cada objeto nos valores dessas chaves

Como o [Mr. Felix](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172301/129) referiu, na versão ES7, há um [novo método para Objetos, o `Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Nesse caso fica ainda mais simples:

```
 const novaArray = array.map(Object.values);
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
const array = [{
  nomePergunta: 'resposta atualizada',
  quantidadeResposta: 5
}, {
  nomePergunta: 'esse foi',
  quantidadeResposta: 4
}];

const novaArray = array.map(Object.values);

console.log(JSON.stringify(novaArray));
```

Comment: Porquê const Sergio?

Comment: @Miguel eu deixei de usar `var` :P

Comment: Ha, por algum motivo em especial?

Comment: @Miguel `const` é mais seguro, é o hábito agora... mas podia ser `var`, ou `let`.

Comment: Não precisava ser tão radical, Sergio. Pobre `var`... :D

Comment: @bfavaretto haha :)

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, funcionou. É possível popular com os valores invertidos, no caso, primeiro a string depois a quantidade? ex: [["resposta atualizada, 5"],["esse foi ", 4]]

Comment: @scooby sim é, podes usar o `.reverse()` assim: https://jsfiddle.net/z3g5auod/

Comment: @Sergio Valeu, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 6):

Com o [ECMAScript 2017+](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values) é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
var arrays = objetos.map(function(obj){return Object.values(obj)});
```

Sendo que `objetos` é a sua array de objetos.

Versão 55 do Chrome, por exemplo, já funciona.

---

Como sugestão do @Sergio ♦, é possível simplificar mais ainda:

```
var arrays = objetos.map(Object.values);
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra abordagem é usando um iterator clássico (apesar de eu preferir map), ler as propriedades do objeto, adicionar em um array temporário para adicionar no novo array de arrays:

```js
var array = [{
    nomePergunta: 'resposta atualizada',
    quantidadeResposta: 5
}, {
    nomePergunta: 'esse foi',
    quantidadeResposta: 4
}];

var novoArray = [];

array.forEach(function(item){
  var tmp = [];
  for (var property in item){
    tmp.push(item[property]);
  }
  novoArray.push(tmp);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(novoArray));
```